# retval = false && someFunction(); // Does someFunction() get called?

Tags: c++

I'm currently working with the Diab 4.4 C++ compiler. It's a total POS, non ANSI-compliant, and I've found problems with it in the past.

I'm wondering if the following problem is an issue with the compiler, or a shortcoming in my knowledge of C++

I realize that the form of x = x && y; will short-circuit the y part if x is false. What the compiler is doing is short-circuiting in the case of x = x && y(); where y() is a non-const function.

```
class A
{
int _a;
A(int a) { _a = a; }
bool someFunction() { _a = 0; return true; } 
};

main(...)
{
A obj = A(1);
bool retval = false;

retval = retval && A.someFunction();

/* What is the value of A._a here? */
}
```

What seems wrong to me is the fact that the compiler is doing this short-circuiting even though someFunction() is not a const function. If it's not const, is the compiler overstepping its bounds by skipping A.someFunction() when retval is false?

Also, I realize this issue can be avoided by writing retval = A.someFunction() && retval; but I'd really like to know why this is happening.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `&&` and `||` operators are defined to evaluate lazily, this is the way the language works. If you want the side effects to always happen, invoke the function first and stash the result, or refactor the function to split the work from the state query.

Comment: Didn't realize evaluations were lazy. Makes more sense now.

Comment: ...or use & if both operands are/return booleans.

Answer (score 10):

Short circuiting applies to all expressions, regardless of `const`-ness. Skipping the call to `someFunction()` is correct.

Answer (score 5):

As others have explained, || and && always perform short-circuit evaluation.

Also note that short-circuit evaluation can be *very useful*, since it lets you write code like this:

```
retval = obj_pointer && obj_pointer->SomeBooleanMethod();
```

Without short-circuit evaluation, this would crash on a NULL pointer.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't matter if the second operand to `&&` is const or not.  After the first operand evaluates to `false` the return value is known, so there's no reason to evaluate the second operand.

If the function has side effects that require it to be executed, put it first.

Answer (score 2):

Short-circuit evaluation has nothing to do with const or non-const.  It happens no matter what.

The statement `A() && B();` will do exactly what `if (A()) B();` does (although it isn't a perfect substitute, as the second one allows an `else`).  This is sometimes used to change a statement into an expression (such as when writing a macro, or embedding it in another statement).

Comment: Note that only the **&&** form is an rvalue.  You cannot say: **C = if (A()) B();**

Comment: Yup, it's closer to C = A() ? A() : B() except A() is evaluated once.

Comment: Bear in mind that && returns 0 or 1 in C and false or true in C++.  It doesn't return either of its operands, unless they happen to have values of 0 or 1 or false or true.

Answer (score 1):

The && operator is also called the shortcut operator, which means it only evaluates the second part if the first part returned true. That's the main difference between && and &:

```
value = func1() && func2(); // evaluates func2() only if func1() returns true

value = func1() & func2(); // evaluates both func1() and func2()
```

Comment: Actually, the `&&` and `&` are much more different than only short-circuit behavior. `((0x10 && 0x01) == 1)` but `((0x10 & 0x01) == 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

For && operator,

```
1 && X = X
0 && X = 0
```

so in case first var is 0, compiler will evaluate the expression to 0, no question, what ever the X is.

Compiler will ignore the X part as it wont impact the result. Here X can be any thing function/variable/expression.....

Comment: That doesn't tell the whole story.  Of course the compiler will do that, if the left-hand part of the expression can be statically known to be true or false.  But furthermore, this will happen AT RUNTIME even if the left-hand expression is something complicated.  That's part of the definition of the C++ language.

Comment: It's also inaccurate.  1 && X will not return X unless X happens to be a boolean value.  In C++, && returns either true or false; in C it returns either 0 or 1.